# Scroll top/bottom button

Tags: javascript, html, css

So I've made a button in the right-bottom corner of my HTML-page, but I was wondering since it's the first time I've made this, if there is another better way to do this, or if you guys can see anything funky about the way I did this?

This post is mostly to learn how to do things the right way, since I'm a beginner at this.

Thanks for your help.

**Here is my code** --> if you want to GOTO: [JSfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Mungax/7m6gtuk9/)

```js
var bottomPage = document.getElementById('bottomPage');
var topPage = document.getElementById('topPage');
var lastScrollTop = 0;

bottomPage.addEventListener('click', scrollBottom);
topPage.addEventListener('click', scrollTop);

// element should be replaced with the actual target element on which you have applied scroll, use window in case of no target element.
window.addEventListener('scroll', function(){ // or element.addEventListener('scroll'....
  var st = window.pageYOffset || document.documentElement.scrollTop;
  if (st > lastScrollTop){
    bottomPage.style.display = 'none';
    topPage.style.display = '';
  } else {
    bottomPage.style.display = '';
    topPage.style.display = 'none';
  }
  lastScrollTop = st <= 0 ? 0 : st;
}, false);
function scrollBottom() {
  window.scrollTo(0,document.body.scrollHeight);
  bottomPage.style.display = 'none';
  topPage.style.display = '';
}
function scrollTop() {
  window.scrollTo(0, 0);
  topPage.style.display = 'none';
  bottomPage.style.display = '';
}
```

```css
body{
  height: 3000px;
  background: white;
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #33ccff 0%, #ff99cc 100%);
}

.right-corder-container {
  position: fixed;
  right: 20px;
  bottom: 20px;
  vertical-align: middle;
  background: #dddddd79;
  text-align: center;
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  border-radius: 100%;
  display: inline-flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  font-size: 25px;
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-decoration: none
}

.right-corder-container img {
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
}

.right-corder-container:hover {
  background: #85858579;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<body>

  <button class='right-corder-container' id='bottomPage' type='button'><img src='https://i.postimg.cc/87f0hmm2/scroll-down.png'></button>

  <button class='right-corder-container' style='display: none;' id='topPage' type='button'><img src='https://i.postimg.cc/Tp4sL4gj/scroll-up.png'></button>


</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

### Some JS points

- [window](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window) is the default object. You seldom need to use it. eg `window.scrollTo` is the same as `scrollTo` as is `window.document` same as `document`.
- You can use the element's id as a JS variable name to reference an element.
- For variables that do not change use constants [const](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/const) rather than [var](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/var) or [let](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/let)
- Avoid setting style values directly to the elements style, rather use CSS rules and selectors to define the styles.
- Keep your code out of the global scope by wrapping it in a IIFE (Immediately Invoked Function Expression)

### HTML/CSS Design

- There is no need to create two buttons. Use one button to simplify your JS.

  Using CSS selectors to define rules for the buttons content lets you use one class name to switch between the up and down options. Add the class name for up, and remove for down.
- There is no need for the `click` events to change the button state as the `scroll` event will fire when you call [Window.scrollTo](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/scrollTo) and that function will change the button's state/
- You added a `type` attribute to button. This is not needed as the button is not part of a form.
- Why did you add the `document.documentElement.scrollTop` [Element.scrollTop](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollTop) when [Window.pageYOffset](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/pageYOffset) is zero?? The two values are the same! BTW `pageYOffset` is an alias for [Window.scrollY](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/scrollY)

### Rewrite

The rewrite tries to keep the JS code a simple as possible.

I removed much of the custom styling (images, background) which can easily be added via HTML/CSS without needing to change the JavaScript

```js
;(()=>{
   var lastPos = 0, scrollToPos = document.body.scrollHeight;

   scrollBtn.addEventListener("click", () => scrollTo(0, scrollToPos));
   addEventListener("scroll", () => {
       scrollToPos = scrollY > lastPos ?  0 : document.body.scrollHeight;
       lastPos = Math.max(0, scrollY);
       scrollBtn.classList.toggle("scrollUp", scrollToPos === 0);
   }, false);
})();
```

```css
body { height: 3000px }
#scrollBtn {
  position: fixed;
  right: 10px;
  bottom: 10px;
  cursor: pointer; 
}
#scrollBtn > .top { display: none } 
#scrollBtn.scrollUp > .top { display: initial } 
#scrollBtn.scrollUp > .bottom {  display: none }
```

```html
  <button id="scrollBtn">
      <span class="top">Top</span>
      <span class="bottom">Bottom</span>
  </button>
```